# ios "Copy to myApp" in activity view

Tags: ios, swift, share-extension

i'm working on developing share extension.

I add NSExtensionActivationRule in info.plist. and my app appear on activity view when it match file type.

But in some app(not for all) trying to share image (ex. google drive..) this (Copy to *) icon has already on the activity view before i start develop. so i have two my app icon on activity view/ first one i created, second already in it.

i try to make a change in plist reomve another attributes, but none of them working correctly

i want to disappear "Copy to MyApp" let me know someone knows about this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally after long research and test i found solution~!!!
there is "Document types" key in info.plist in project.

My Project has been set All files supports so I delete this property .

Now that Save to MyApp icon disappear in UIActivityViewController.

Comment: which info.plist use??

Comment: @RaviPadsala  Every project has own plist. If you has your ios application project you has plist in your project.

Comment: I am using ShareExtension so there is create it info.plist file

Comment: hmm... i changed documet types in my container project not extension. so.. i'm not sure about extension's info file